# Check proof that any integer can be written as the difference of two positive integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm working my way through Martin Liebeck's "A Concise Introduction to Pure Mathematics", and one of the statements he asks the reader to prove is: $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\exists m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m \gt 0$, $n \gt 0$, and $x = m - n$.

The way I thought of going about this is to use a contrapositive proof since it feels easier to find counter-examples. So I rewrote the statement as: $\exists x \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that $\forall m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $m \gt 0$, $n \gt 0$, and $x \ne m - n$.

Now we proceed by cases:

When $m \gt n$ we subtract $n$ on both sides so we get $m - n \gt 0$. We take $x = 0$ so this case holds.

When $m = n$ we subtract $n$ on both sides to get $m - n = 0$. We take $x = 1$ so this case holds as well.

Finally, when $m \lt n$ we subtract $n$ to get $m - n \lt 0$. We take $x = 0$, and this holds as well.

We've proven that all three cases hold. Now because we've proven the contrapositive, the original statement holds as well.

My questions are:

- First, is this a valid proof?
- Second, is this actually a contrapositive?
- Third, this feels clunky. Is there a nicer way to prove the statement?

Thanks.

Comment: @FShrike Why would $m>0$ then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your contrapositive is wrong. It should be
$$\exists x \in \mathbb{Z}\text{ such that }\forall m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\text{, if }m>0\text{ and }n>0\text{ then }x\ne m-n$$
But a direct proof is simpler: if $x\ge 0$, we can take $m=x+1$ and $n=1$; and if $x<0$, we can take $m=1$ and $n=1-x$.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. The contrapositive felt wrong, but I couldn't put my finger on why. I also thought of a direct proof on those lines, but wasn't sure if it just works like that.

Answer (score 1):

> Second, is this actually a contrapositive?

I'm not comfortable with it, or the proof in general. There is no implication as stated, necessary for a contrapositive. I guess you could rewrite it as

$$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Zp}{\Z_{>0}}
(x \in \Z) \implies (\exists m,n \in \Zp)(m-n = x)$$

Then the contrapositive is

$$(\forall m,n \in \Zp)(m - n \ne x) \implies x \not \in \Z$$

I certainly see no argument given for why $x$ would be a noninteger, just that a particular $x$ perhaps is not equal to some difference $m-n$.

---

> Third, this feels clunky. Is there a nicer way to prove the statement?

By construction.

- If $x>0$, pick $x+1$ and $1$ as your integers.
- If $x=0$, pick $n$ and $n$ as your integers, for any $n>0$.
- If $x<0$, pick $1$ and $1+|x|$ as your integers.